# recording screen issue

Tags: c#, windows, media, encoder

I am using Windows Media Encoder 9, and in a dual screen environment, I want to record only the primary screen. Any ideas or samples how to implement this? Non-programming solution is also appreciated. :-)

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

I use [AimOne Screen recorder](http://www.aimonesoft.com/screenrecorder.html) for all my recordings.  It's very easy to use and at a reasonable price.  It allows you to choose that exact region you'd like to record.  You can even get the free trial to see if you like it or not.

Comment: It is not free and no SDK to customize. It is why I select WME. Any ideas or solutions on WME?